# Android-UIAutomator | Webdriver | Identify value of focusable property for an element

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, android-uiautomator

I have an android app. in which verification for Login can only be done using the email-element's **"focusable" attribute**  which changes from 'false' to 'true' on login.

I am using webdriver for automation and want to verify the email-element's focusable attribute so that I can verify login functionality .

Ex:  if(abc.getAttribute('focusable')=='true')
       // verify login success
     else 
        // login fail

But the above condition never works i.e.  the script does not enter the if block due to which else block gets executed .

I am new to Android app and not sure if focusable can be used like above .

Pls help!!!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had the HTML I might be able to provide a better answer but a couple things I noticed...

Since this is Java, your conditional won't work. It should be

```
if(abc.getAttribute("focusable").equals("true"))
```

You can't use `==` with Strings. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more info.

Also you are using single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") around `String`s. Java won't like that. Single quotes are for `char`.